# Ruby - Downcase on string values in a hash that also contains nil values

Tags: ruby, hash, lowercase

Currently attempting to adjust all the string values of a hash to lowercase. This hash contains multiple value types (nil, string, integer) so running across the entire hash with downcase spits out an error due to the nil values in the hash.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method "downcase!" for nil:NilClass
```

I'm pretty brand new to Ruby and I wasn't sure how best to run through this hash and skip the nil or integer values. I've attempted to use .map to convert every value to string and then downcase the values, but I'm either not seeing any difference in the end result or I get an error.

```
testHash = testHash.map(&:to_s)
testHash.map(&:downcase!)
(I've also attempted testHash.each {|k,v| v.downcase!}
```

I'm sure most of this is me just not knowing how to write this out in Ruby correctly. Please let me know if you need additional info and thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the value is a valid string before downcasing

```
testHash.each { |k, v| v.downcase! if v.is_a?(String) }
```

Comment: I've ran this and it goes through with no error. But when calling on one of the values I know has an uppercase letter in it, I'm still seeing it capitalized. Any idea why it's not actually adjusting, even with the ! at the end of downcase?

Comment: You could also use `v.downcase! if v.respond_to?(:downcase!)` which is slightly more duck-typish. It's sometimes better to ask what a thing can *do* rather than what a thing *is*.

Comment: Laura, this should work. Can you edit your question to show an example hash where this doesn't work? Include just a few keys in the example, perhaps two or three.

Comment: When I make a test hash, it works but running it against the code I have is not working so I realize this is an issue with my existing data. It doesn't seem to be working against this CSV I am hashing. Still trying to figure out this issue.

Comment: I realize my hash is actually an array of hashes, which is why this isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {a: nil, b: "Someword", c: 1}
h.map {|k,v| v.downcase! if v.is_a? String}
puts h #=> {:a=>nil, :b=>"someword", :c=>1}
```

This will work. I am mapping through the hash and check for values that are strings, and then running the `downcase!` method.